# MySQL: Is it possible to have more than one slave/database-replica on the same server?

Tags: mysql, master-slave

I'd like to have 3 replicas of my MySQL master server. One should have 0 delay, the second replica should have 12 hours delay and the third one 48 hours delay. Is it possible to have this on the same slave server? Right now, I'm running the 0 delay slave, but would like to setup the delays in the same server to safe costs.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this is very strange. it is worth to add *why* you want to do this. an alternative solution may arise that will solve your problem.

Comment: So the "ideal" scenario is for having "hot" backups running. So if we spot a failure we can have margin for not loosing data (vs Daily dumps).

Comment: what happens if you spot the failure after 48 hours? daily dumps **do** server a purpose. (im just saying you should continue of course the daily dumps regardless of hot backups). also you should try http://dba.stackexchange.com/ for this question

Comment: Yes, of course, we will keep daily dumps (mysqldump). But its easier to do a recovery from a "hot" db than having to recover a dump. I've searched dba, but nothing found. I had to register so I thought it was worth the shot asking here before.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible as you can see at: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-delayed.html

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.